# How can I define top vertical gap for wrapfigure?

Tags: graphics, wrapfigure, wrapfig

I use the `wrapfigure` package to make text wrapped around an image. Everything is fine except one thing: I want to move it lower on the page and make some (2 or 3) lines come before it. On the image you see, that the first line of the paragraph "wants" to wrap the image on the top, but can't.

[image: Here is my current result]

Command is:

```
Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. 


\begin{wrapfigure}[16]{o}{5cm}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{img01.jpg}
\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
\caption*{This is a figure caption.}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First set the text without the image, then add the `wrapfig` at the point a natural linebreak occurs.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig,graphicx}

\begin{document}

Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text
here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text here. Text
here. 


Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum
gravida mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id,
vulputate a, magna.%
    \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{o}{5cm}
        \centering
        \vspace*{-10pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \end{wrapfigure}%
 Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant
morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus
vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu tellus sit amet tortor
gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium quis, viverra
ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean faucibus.
Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla.
Curabitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh
mi, congue eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci
sit amet orci dignissim rutrum.

Nam dui ligula, fringilla a, euismod sodales, sollicitudin vel, wisi.
Morbi auctor lorem non justo. Nam lacus libero, pretium at, lobortis
vitae, ultricies et, tellus. Donec aliquet, tortor sed accumsan
bibendum, erat ligula aliquet magna, vitae ornare odio metus a mi. Morbi
ac orci et nisl hendrerit mollis. Suspendisse ut massa. Cras nec ante.
Pellentesque a nulla. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis
parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aliquam tincidunt urna. Nulla
ullamcorper vestibulum turpis. Pellentesque cursus luctus mauris.


\end{document}
```

Comment: David, I want "consectetuer" to come after "amet,", I use your commands, but the blank place still stays there. Even if I add \vspace.
I also want previous paragraph to be left sided, so I add a blank line after "Text here" block. I use book layout, A5

Comment: Also I changed wrapfig to wrapfig2 and
```\captionsetup[figure]{labelsep=period,font=small,labelfont=it}``` now doesn't work

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy "I want "consectetuer" to come after "amet,""  sorry I can not guess what you mean: word order is not changed in any way. I just grabbed some text from somewhere  rather than use `lipsum` package which is hard to use for examples where the insertion is mid text

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy I just tested the above with `\usepackage{wrapfig2,graphicx}` and get identical output.

Comment: Please look at the image. I want the first line or two first lines to occupy all width of the page, but now if i add space with \vspace the image simply goes down

Comment: you asked for first 3 lines of the paragraph to be full width and the image cut out to start below that, which is exactly what I show here.  If you add `vspace` then naturally things move down,  just as adding negative  vspace as here moves it up, isn't that what you expect? @NikolayYasinskiy

Comment: the first line above is `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer`  is that not  _"I want "consectetuer" to come after "amet,""_ ???? @NikolayYasinskiy

Comment: Sorry, may be It's a problem of hyphenation. The right side of text is never smooth 100% some words go over the edge.

Comment: @NikolayYasinskiy you are hyphenating mock-latin with english hypenation rules which does not work well (although the example here is OK) specify latin via `babel` package or use english text for better hyphenation

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{wrapfig2,lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-8]
    \begin{wrapfigure}[12]{o}{5cm}
        \centering
        \vspace*{-10pt}
        \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        %\captionsetup{labelsep=period}
        \caption{This is a figure caption.}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```